# VBA nested dictionary duplicate/clone

Tags: vba, dictionary

I have a main dictionary which contains a dictionary as an item, which contains an dictionary as an item, so all in all three nested dictionaries. I want to duplicate/clone my main dictionary to work with it, but don't want that there are any changes in my original dictionary. I tried to duplicate it as that:

```
For Each Key In MainDict.Keys
        CloneDict.Add Key, MainDict(Key) 
Next
```

When I do it like that and do changes in the sub-dictionary in my clone, it changes it in my main dictionary aswell. Is there any clone/copy method which gives me a whole copy and not just a reference to the sub-dictionaries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More a thought than a real answer, but probably you'll have to do the copy operation for every level of nested dictionary, beginning with the lowest one. 
Because I don't think there is a method to completly clone a three level dictionay. Afaik there is even no method to hard copy a list/dictionary in VBA at all, but I could be wrong at this point.